# Format column as Zip Code when exporting from ag-grid

Tags: excel, ag-grid, excel-import

I am exporting to Excel using the Enterprise Ag-Grid built in solutions. Whenever I export a zipcode, any zipcode that begins with `0` loses that in the Excel file.  I know that Excel supports a special Zip Code format, however, I keep striking out on my attempts.

```
        {
            headerName: 'ZIP',
            type: 'zip code',
            filter: 'number',
            unSortIcon: true,
            field: 'Zip',
            filterParams: {
                filterOptions: this.filterOption,
                clearButton: true,
                applyButton: true
            },
            minWidth: 120
        }
```

That is how the column is currently defined within the  `columnDefs` of the `gridOptions`.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or insight you may have.

Regards,

Youssef

Comment: It's not about `ag-grid` export, seems that `Excel` just doesn't display it as you expect, check `format` in `Excel`.

Comment: I've come across this same issue.  Any help as to how to configure ag-grid to handle this without the user reformatting the cell in MS Excel would be very helpful.  Thanks in advance for anyone who knows an ag-grid configuration to solve this.

Answer (score -1):

You can format the required cells in your spreadsheet as "00000" which will show the required formatting.  Format cells->Special->Zip Code.